# What is struct NIL { typedef NIL Head; }?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am reading about template metaprogramming. I could not understand what these lines mean; the following code concerns about doing metaprogramming on a linked list.

```
struct NIL {
typedef NIL Head;
typedef NIL Tail;
};

template <typename H, typename T=NIL> struct Lst {
    typedef H Head;
    typedef T Tail;
};

template <int N> struct Int{ static const int result = N; };
typedef Lst< Int<1>, Lst< Int<2>, Lst< Int<3> > > > OneTwoThree;
```

The above is coming from https://monoinfinito.wordpress.com/series/introduction-to-c-template-metaprogramming/ .
I would greatly appreciate any guidance as to what it means to have struct NIL, which has typedef NIL Head, and typedef NIL Tail. Nil is a type, sure, but if I have typedef NIL Head, for example, does it mean i have another recursive Head and Tail within each Head?

Comment: There's a joke to be made about `NIL`ism in here somewhere.

Comment: I've seen some bad names in my time, but `NIL` is right up there as award-winningly bad. That name is astonishingly misleading. Anyone who recommends doing this is a mad scientist, and I don't mean the good kind.

Comment: Presumably it stands for Node in List, but you're far better off spelling it out as `NodeInList` rather than `NIL`

Comment: @tadman it's actually a pretty common name for NULL-like stuff, it's used in LISP and Lua (although here the inspiration is clearly LISP).

Comment: In C++11 and later one typically uses `std::tuple` instantiations as type lists. The techniques from Modern C++ (and the Loki library) are no longer very relevant. You would do well to get a book from after 2011.

Comment: @tadman "Nil" has been the established name for the empty list for well over fifty years.

Comment: @Tas No, it means "nothing", and has for over five hundred years.

Comment: @molbdnilo Exactly why making a class called NIL that is *not* that is a bad idea.

Comment: @MatteoItalia This class is not in any way a "NULL-like" anything, that's why it's a bad idea.

Comment: @tadman It's a type that represents the empty (type-level) list of types, so it's a good name. Of course, `Lst` should be renamed `Cons`, and `Head` and `Tail` should be `Car` and `Cdr`...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, `typedef NIL Head;` doesn't mean you have *a* `NIL` within each `NIL`.

It simply means `NIL::Head` is another name for `NIL`. Ditto for `NIL::Tail`.

This does mean you can write the types recursively, for example `NIL::Head::Tail::Tail::Tail::Head::Head` is also a name for `NIL`. However there's no actual recursive type here.

Comment: FYI @user7865286 if you feel this answer answers your completely unequivocally, you can [mark it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) by pressing the _tick_.

Answer (score 2):

`NIL` is just another name for nothing.

It isn't `NULL` because that was taken.

Here, we are creating a LISP like linked list of "head" and "tail".  To represent the end of the list, place a `NIL`.

`NIL` satisfies the layout of a list, but one with both head and tail being `NIL`.  Myself I'd be tempted to have written:

```
struct NIL;

template <typename H, typename T=NIL> struct Lst {
  typedef H Head;
  typedef T Tail;
};
```

struct NIL:Lst{};

to make `NIL` as the name of the empty list more clear.

By making `NIL` have head & tail, some template metaprogramming becomes easier (and some becomes harder).  The fact that they are the same type does mean that in one sense the `NIL` list has an infinite length; but in another sense it has zero length, as we define length to be the distance until we reach `NIL`.

`typedef`s are not "within" the type, they are defined inside like how data members are.  They are more like pointers than members.  In non template metaprogramming:

```
struct node {
  node* head, *tail;
};
struct NIL:node{
  NIL() : node{this, this} {}
};
```

Comment: It's "nil" because "nil" is a noun and "null" is an adjective.